# How do I add a field for a message attribute from another node to the Attribute Editor?

Tags: maya, mel

Suppose I have 3 nodes called GrandParent, Parent and Child. Child is connected to Parent and Parent is connected to GrandParent by Message attributes.

I would like to add a custom field in the Attribute Editor for GrandParent that refers to Child. Basically, a field for the message attribute of Parent receiving the connection to Child, but show that field in GrandParent.

It would look like what you get with `editorTemplate -label "Brush Details" -addControl "child";` in AEParentTemplate.mel where child is the Message attribute for connecting a Child node.
[image: Message attribute]

Except that I would like to add this to the Attribute Editor for GrandParent.

I managed to add other attributes from Parent to GrandParent by using `editorTemplate -callCustom "parent_new" "parent_replace"` in AEGrandParent.mel. In parent_new I create a dummy Parent node

```
string $dummyParent = `createNode -skipSelect "Parent"`;
```

And I use it to add fields from Parent to the attribute editor of GrandParent. For example 
`attrFieldSliderGrp -attribute ($dummyParent + ".numericValue")` adds a field and slider for a float attribute called numericValue in Parent. I can do the same for a color attribute with `attrColorSliderGrp -label $tmpStr -attribute ($dummyParent + ".color")`

Then at the end of parent_new I delete the temporary node and I keep the values in the fields updated in parent_replace by updating the attribute reference for the fields (for example `attrFieldSliderGrp -e -attribute "parentNode1.numericValue" "parentNumericValueField";`).

My problem is that I can't find how to do the same for a Message attribute. I tried creating a attrFieldGrp with `attrFieldGrp -attribute ($dummyParent + ".child");` but this crashes Maya 2014. I tried the same with attrControlGrp `attrControlGrp -attribute ($dummyParent + ".child");` which gives an error that Message attributes are not supported by attrControlGrp.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to use `attrNavigationControlGrp` to create the control. This control does not need the dummy Parent node and will create the UI for node connections.